# Redeploy Yesod app with Keter without recreating database

Tags: postgresql, haskell, yesod

I am writing my first app with Yesod, and I've got it to a state where it works, but I want to keep adding little things to it. So far, every time I redeploy with keter by swapping in the new package, the database gets recreated for that app. How can I redeploy without that  effect? I am not very familiar with postgres, so a workaround would be great as well.

Edit: I also scaffolded it with SQLite, if that makes a difference. I have been looking all over and still can't figure this out.

Comment: Are you redeploying an app with the same name or a different name? Keter tracks databases based on the name of the Keter bundle, so if you keep renaming it, that will definitely cause a new database to be created.

Comment: I have been using the same name for the bundle, but I would usually swap in a Keter bundle from a different base location for the app. I just realized that I still have the app calling


    `Database.Persist.Store.runPool dbconf (runMigration migrateAll) p`


in `makeFoundation`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I figured out eventually was that I couldn't make it keep the data if it was scaffolded with Sq-lite.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to what the accepted answer says, you can actually do this. In the sqlite.yml configuration, you just set the path to a place that it has access to.

My current setup is, I've made a folder at `/opt/keter/database` and then my config for production is,

```
Production:
  database: /opt/keter/database/HsCMS_production.sqlite3
  poolsize: 100
  <<: *defaults
```

which will keep the database persistent across deployments. You should be aware of when you alter the database though, it still needs to do migrations.